# cufon problem background image

Tags: wordpress, cufon

I'm developing a website and for the first time i found problems using cufon... if you think u know about cofon check this..

http://universite.jvsoftware.com

If you open with firefox and IE, you will notice in the navigation bar, when you over the titles will appear a border (actually is an image) but if you open it with chrome or safari, that image doesnt appear.... the cufon script is easy to find in the source code, also the css.

Let me know if you know how to fix that!!

Kind Regards

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with cufon. Most likely a direct CSS issue. Have you tried the site without cufon? does the hover work properly then?

Comment: hey! yeah I did it and worked fine, it started failling after i just set the cufon script, i try to modify the css an notice that if i move the image like 10px upper i can see it!!! thats weird... with 9px it desappear :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution to your Cufon problem, but I would just recommend going with a different font replacement tool altogether if you can help it. I like the performance of Typekit or Google Fonts much better than Cufon, but that's just a matter of preference.